# how can i divide numerator by any similar to 0.0110932 in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm getting error like PHP

> Warning: Division by zero error.

I'm still and want to calculate some problems. If you can tell me, how can calculate antilog / log inverse with examples, I'll be more satisfied.

```
<?
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
       $P=$_POST['P'];  // P=100000
       $rate=$_POST['rate']; // rate = 10.5
       $R=($rate/100);
       $N=$_POST['N']; // N = 78
       echo $P ."<br>" ;
       echo $R ."<br>" ;
       echo $N ."<br>" ;
       $NEW=($R/12);   // NEW = .00875
       $aa = (1+($NEW)); // aa = 1.00875
       $ab = bcpow('$aa', '$N',16); // ab = 1.9729529246182467
       $ac = ($ab-1); // ac = 0.9729529246182467
       $ad = bcdiv('$ab', '$ac', 3); // Div by Zero Error 
       $M = ($P*$NEW) *($ad);
       echo "The Installment is : " . $M . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code you are trying.  Edit it into your question.

Comment: A redneck solution could be doing something like `$ans = ($x * 1E9) / ($near_0 * 1E9)`. But well ...

Comment: Thank you for editing in the code.  Now, which of those divisions is the one causing the error?  Please copy and paste the complete wording of the error message.

Comment: What `$_POST` values and what line are causing the issue? Come on, it's *your* question—we should not need to beg you to provide details.

Comment: if $ab=1.06690 and $ac=0.06690; The PHP says that It is Division by Zero Error - How can I overcome it - I'm still new for programming and php. @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Comment: $ac = ($ab-1);
       $ad = bcdiv('$ab', '$ac', 3);
Warning: bcdiv() [function.bcdiv]: Division by zero in /home/a9155456/public_html/loantest.php on line 43
 @Charles

Comment: Are you positive `$N=$_POST['N'];` is not empty or 0?

Answer (score 5):

The line with the problem:

```
$ad = bcdiv('$ab', '$ac', 3); // Div by Zero Error
```

The problem here is because `$ab` and `$ac` are in quotes. They shouldn't be.

Having them in quotes means that PHP sees `$ab` as being a string consisting of the characters `$`, `a` and `b`, instead of the numeric value of the `$ab` variable.

Remove the quotes, and it should start working.

The same applies to the `bcpow()` line.

Answer (score 1):

`bcpow('$aa', '$N',16);` are you sure these variables get parsed? They are treated as a string in single quotes, and since there is no number they might be just bogus. (typing `$aa^$n` on a calculator will fail).

You can use `bcpow("'".$aa."'", "'".$N."'",16);` or try using double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To narrow down where your issue is coming from:
`string bcdiv ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale ] )`

bcdiv will return `Division by zero` only if the right operand is 0, so you can backtrace this  by assuming `$ac` is your culprint. Try echoing `$ac` before the `bcdiv` function call to ensure it is not empty.

I'm willing to bet that this line `$ac = ($ab-1); // ac = 0.9729529246182467`
`$ac` is going negative.

You should also remove your single quotes, don't take the manual so literal. You can still pass in an int or double and the function will convert it for you. even if you cast the variable as a double.

```
//WITHOUT QUOTES
$ab = '1.9729529246182467';
$ac = ($ab-1);
echo bcdiv($ab, $ac, 3);
//output (2.027)

//WITH QUOTES
$ab = '1.9729529246182467';
$ac = ($ab-1);
echo bcdiv($ab, '$ac', 3);
//output Warning (2): bcdiv() [function.bcdiv]: Division by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your code as well, but here is the code that calculate Antilog / log of a value

```
<?php

$log = 11;
$e   = 2.718281828;
$dn  = 1;

// Calculate Antilog of $log = 11
$ans = pow($e, $log);
$antilog = round($ans*10000)/10000;
echo "<br /> Antilog : ".$antilog;

// Calculate Log of $log = 11
$ans = log($log)/$dn;
$log = round($ans*10000)/10000;
echo "<br /> Log : ".$log;

// Calculate Antilog / Log of $log = 11
echo "<br /> Antilog / Log : ".($antilog / $log);
?>
```

Result:

```
Antilog : 59874.1416
Log : 2.3979
Antilog / Log : 24969.407231327
Hope this help you, if else please provide more details (comments) on your code.
```